# How to divide the array into a 15 X 15 row and column?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I split the array into 15x15 row and column?

**Example**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

arr1 = []
print(arr1)
```

The result will be:

```
['I', 'O', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'N', 'O', 'W', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'O', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', 'M', 'T', '0', '0', '0', 'U', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'X', 'I', '0', '#', 'W', 'M', 'S', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'W', 'H', 'T', 'F', 'A', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'I', '0', '0', 'D', '0', '0', 'N', 'E', '0', 'M', 'A', 'I', 'D', 'E', 'N', '#', '0', '0', 'H', 'A', 'G', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Z', '0', 'U', '0', 'Y', '0', '0', 'L', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'N', 'O', 'H', '0', 'T', 'H', 'O', 'N', 'R', 'C', 'V', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'O', '0', 'I', '0', 'U', '0', '0', 'D', 'I', 'S', 'C', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'L', '0', 'N', '0', '0', '0', 'M', 'C', 'I', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', '0', 'G', '0', '0', 'H', 'A', 'Y', 'S', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'R', 'E', '0', '0', '0', '#', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'F', 'O', 'R', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Q', 'U', 'A', '0', '0', '0', 'O', '0', '0']
```

What I want to is to make the output into like this image:

[image]

How do I divide the result to be a 15x15 array?

Comment: 15*15=225, but you only have 196 values. Also, the characters in your input do not correspond to the characters in your so-called desired output.

Comment: 2 dimensional matrix can be presented as array of arrays like
matrix = [ 
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ,
     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11] ...
              ] 
So in order to print it like in the image you can just use for loop like:

for i in matrix:
    print(i)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the list you provided doesn't have any match to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the array method `reshape`

```
arr = np.array([ ... ])
arr = arr.reshape(15,15)
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question, please mark it as the solution with the ✓ mark.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you want, but IIUC:

```
print(np.array([arr1[i:i + 15] for i in range(0, len(arr1), 15)]))
```